# Solving the equation $ f^{-1}(x)=f(x)$

Tags: functions

I attempted to solve the equation given in the title for the function;

$$f: \mathbb R_{++} \to\mathbb R_{++}; \quad f(x)=x^2(x+2)$$

I understand that the problem is equivalent to solving $f(f(x))=x$
but since this seemed like too much work, I had a look at the solution and it stated that;

$$ f^{-1}(x)=f(x) \Longrightarrow  f(x)=x$$

I don't understand why this is the case. Can someone please explain this?

Thanks

Comment: It is not true in general; although $f(x)=x$ implies $f(f(x))=x$ the reverse is not always true. Consider $f(x)=-x$

Comment: Your particular function isn't invertible for negative $x$, so $f^{-1}$ doesn't even make sense in the first place without giving the domain and codomain of $f$.

Comment: Were you given an interval to restrict $f$ to?

Comment: Thanks.That makes sense.  So does that mean I must solve the equation $f(f(x))=x$ ?

Comment: @AlexR,Clarinetist, I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that. Its domain is $x>0$.

Comment: @J.Gudal You should first try to find out where $f$ is invertible (It's not invertible on $\mathbb R$. See its [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x^3%2B2x^2)

Comment: I've proven its invertibility for  x>0. x is real btw.

Comment: That map is self inverse. Such maps are called involutions.

Comment: @mvw No, it's not. $f\circ f$ is a degree-$9$ polynomial, not the identity.

Comment: I mean the general $f $ from the title, I have not checked the given $f$ in the text if it complies.

Comment: what about 1/x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although $f(f(x))=x\implies f(x)=x$ is not always true, it *is* true if $f$ is an increasing function (even if only weakly increasing).

Suppose that $f(x)=y$ and $f(y)=x$. If $x\le y$, then $f(x)=y\le f(y)=x$, and vice-versa.
So either way, both $x\le y$ and $y\le x$ are true, and thus $x=y$ and $f(x)=x$.

So your book is not off the rails; this is a valid approach to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f: \mathbb R_{++} \to \mathbb R_{++}$ is settled in the comments, your idea is good. Write $f(x) = x^3 + 2x^2$ to reduce the complexity of $f(f(x))$ and then solve
$$f(f(x)) = (x^3+2x^2)^3 + 2(x^3 + 2x^2)^2 \stackrel!= x \qquad x>0$$
We can expand this to
$$x^9 + 6x^8 + 12x^7 + 8x^6 + 2x^6 + 8x^5 + 8x^4 - x = 0$$
Then divide by $x$ since $x\ne 0$ for
$$x^8 + 6x^7 + 12x^6 + 8x^5 + 2x^5 + 8x^4 + 8x^3 - 1 = 0$$
WolframAlpha tells us there is only one positive root at
$$x = \sqrt 2 - 1$$

Comment: I got to that stage but thought it was too hideous, and so must be wrong. I think the solution had an error. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AlexR The implication is not false in this case - see my answer.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Yes, I saw it, but the solution should have mentioned _why_ it wasn't false ;)

Comment: The solution assumed that $f(x)=x$ and so concluded that $x= \sqrt{2}-1$

Comment: @J.Gudal I had a mistake in my original post. Fixed it not to come up with the same solution.

Comment: @AlexR Thanks, I didn't really think of using WolframAlpha, though its nice to know the idea turned out fine in then end.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem were to find *a* solution of $f^{-1}(x)=f(x)$ with $x\gt0$, then the hint would be useful if the implication were reversed, i.e.,

> $$f(x)=x\implies f^{-1}(x)=f(x)$$

Setting $x^2(x+2)=x$ leads to the equation

$$x^2+2x-1=0$$

which has positive solution $x=\sqrt2-1$.

But we can say more.  Borrowing the degree-$8$ polynomial from AlexR's answer, we know that $x^2+2x-1$ must be a factor of it.  And indeed it is:

$$x^8+6x^7+12x^6+10x^5+8x^4+8x^3-1=(x^2+2x-1)(x^6+4x^5+5x^4+4x^3+5x^2+2x+1)$$

and since the coefficients of $x^6+4x^5+5x^4+4x^3+5x^2+2x+1$ are all positive, the degree-$8$ polynomial has no other solutions with $x\gt0$.  So $x=\sqrt2-1$ is not only *a* solution, it's the *only* solution.