# Condition for which the real roots of the polynomial is none

Tags: polynomials, roots

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1302643/1021792 in this solution given it was being said as coefficients are all positive hence the equation $x^6 + 4x^5 + 5x^4 + 4x^3 +2x +1 = 0$ has no real number solution , but its in which cases always  true that if all the coefficients are non negative then there will be no real roots at all ? As i think there are many counter examples like $x^2 = 0$ , $x^3 +3x = 0$ , i am guessing it might be true when the constant term is non zero , but was not able to show it .

Comment: The answer you link refers to "*solutions with $\color{red}{x \gt 0}$*".

Comment: If the coefficients are all positive and the constant term is positive then there is no way you can have a solution with $x>0$ since that would be a sum of positive numbers equal to zero... Solutions with $x<0$ would still be possible however i.e. $x+1=0$

Comment: The most general way is [Strum's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem), which counts number of real zeros

Comment: Oh i see, now i understood , thanks @MichaelMorrow  . Okay dxiv

Comment: Thats intersting @SeewooLee thanks